# Symfony 1.4: Call to undefined function visual_effect()

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am moving a project from SF 1.3.6 to Symfony 1.4.

I am using statements like the one below, very frequently in my code:

```
link_to_function('[Cancel]', visual_effect('blind_up', array('duration'=>0.5)));
```

I am now getting the error shown in the title of this question. I read in a (SF) forum that the Jquery plugin can be used to achieve this.

Can anyone show how to replicate this functionality/behavior by using the new plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The visual_effect function was part of the JavascriptHelper up until version 1.4 where it was deprecated.

To get it working in 1.4 just install the [sfJqueryReloadedPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfJqueryReloadedPlugin). There is solid documentation on what is supports.

To install the plugin go to you symfony console:

```
./symfony plugin:install sfJqueryReloadedPlugin
```

Make sure the the plugin in enabled in you project configuration then include the jQueryHelper where required:

```
<?php use_helper('jQuery'); ?>
```

Comment: I am not sure I like this new way of doing things at all. jQuery is already a 'standard' and given the amount of effort required to bring all my templates in line, my time would be better spent on learning how to use jQuery directly, rather than learning an API which is merely a wrapper around jQuery - especially, since the wrapper API is likely to be subject to YET another non backward compatable upgrade (if Symfony developers history is anything to go by). Thanks for your answer all the same. For now though, I think I will stay on 1.3.6 alittle longer.

Comment: I agree with you. You should take the time to learn the jQuery framework. I simply answered the question "Can anyone show how to replicate this functionality/behavior by using the new plugin?".

Comment: Also the api calls, for the most part, should be exactly the same. So in order to upgrade you should simply be able to add the jQueryHelper to the affected templates. You shouldn't have to change any other code.